# Memorization of the Talmud by Tosafists

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, tosfot

I have heard a story (referenced [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=oJOvpkHg7msC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=ri%20students%20each%20memorized%20a%20tractate%20of%20the%20gemara&source=bl&ots=GdVruISUyU&sig=-4Bfk_Ug5x7W1XcrhRSqAl3P7ak&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pXNrVaCgLMHaoASC94DICg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ri%20students%20each%20memorized%20a%20tractate%20of%20the%20gemara&f=false) for example) about R. Isaac of Dampierre making sure that each tractate of the talmud be memorized by one of his students.

What are the earliest sources for this story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tzeidah Lederech](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14130&st=&pgnum=5) (R' Menachem ben Zerach, ?-1374):

> ורבינו יצחק בן אחותו של רבינו תם הנודע
>   בעל התוספות אשר למד ולימד בישיבה. כי העידו לי רבותי הצרפתים בשם רבותם כי נודע ונתפרסם שהיו
>   לומדים לפניו ס׳ רבנים שכל א׳ מהם היה שומע ההלכה שהיה מגיד גם היה לומד כל אחד לבדו מסכתא שלא
>   היה לומד חברו והיו חוזרים על פה ולא היה מגיד רבינו יצחק הלכה שלא היה בפיהם בין כלם כל הגמ׳ בין
>   עיניהם כאותה הגדה עד שנתבררו להם כל ספיקות שבגמרא

So he says he was told this by his French teachers in the name of their teachers.